# WP Возможно ли в ячейке БД хранить json?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, база-данных

Есть ли возможность в ячейке MySQL сохранять ответ от сервера формата json размером ~3.5Мб ?
С периодическим обновлением этих данных?

*читал что там ограничение на количество знаков допустимых к записи в ячейку.

Comment: Смотря как будете хранить. Тот же clob позволяет 4ГБ сохранять в одной ячейке

Comment: То есть, если необходимо хранить большой объем данных то в Type вместо TEXT ставить BLOB ?

Comment: *читал что там ограничение* Читать надо официальную документацию, а не сомнительные сочинения по её мотивам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The JSON Data Type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html)

> The space required to store a JSON document is roughly the same as for LONGBLOB or LONGTEXT;

[Data Type Storage Requirements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html)

> | Data Type | Storage Required |
> | --- | --- |
> | .. | .. |
> | LONGBLOB, LONGTEXT | L + 4 bytes, where L < 2<sup>32</sup> |
> | .. | .. |

Т.е. максимальный размер - 4 Гбайт. Причём это размер не исходного текстового, а формализованного бинарного представления. Так что мегабайты туда пролезут со свистом...

Главное - не напорись на ограничение размера входящего пакета.